# redirecting contents of file as standard input to executable file linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell, ssh, makefile

So I have a problem in SSH shell. I have a proj1.cpp file that reads in text from standard input into a string called "**word**". Afterwards I use a makefile in order to compile that into an executable file (proj1.x). Then in the SSH shell i do a command like "proj1.x < test0" which redirects the contents of file "test0" into the standard input of "proj1.x" (basically, to put the text in test0 into the programs string "**word**"). It's working fine but it seems as though it cuts off after reading in about about 30 or so characters. However when i simply run "proj1.cpp" with code blocks or whatever, everything works fine (for the line of text I enter whatever its size is) So I don't know what the issue is.

I was thinking it's possible that the problem is i'm using "getline(cin, word);" which reads in 1 line of text from standard input to the string named "word", but some of the content of the files I'm redirecting have several lines. What code would I use to go about reading all the text from the standard input (i guess until the program is terminated?) So when I redirect a file to the standard input, it reads all the content and uploads that to the string "**word**". Perhaps a while loop? Or, please comment if you think it's some other problem.

what I'm using now:

```
string word;
getline(cin, word);
```

my makefile:

```
proj1.x: proj1.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

clean: 
    rm -f *.o *.x core.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To gather all content you can use a `while` loop or some other variant such as a `for` loop:

```
std::string content;

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    content += line;
}
```